# Azure devops- Running the multiple release from single release defnition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to invoke the multiple releases definition using REST API.Also enabled multiple agents for each Agent job. But even after triggering multiple releases the second release is in Queue and not at all starting. Is there any way to start the deployment parallelly from a single release defition.

Comment: Are you licensed for additional parallel jobs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops#view-available-parallel-jobs

Answer (score 0):

Parallel jobs have different restrictions depending on the agents you use and your project is public or private.

**Microsoft-hosted agent**

If your jobs run on the pool of Microsoft-hosted agents. Microsoft provides a free tier of service by default in every organization:

- Public project: 10 free Microsoft-hosted parallel jobs that can run
  for up to 360 minutes (6 hours) each time, with no overall time limit
  per month.
- Private project: One free job that can run for up to 60 minutes each
  time, until you've used 1,800 minutes (30 hours) per month.

**Note**:When you purchase your first Microsoft-hosted parallel job, the number of parallel jobs you have in the organization is still 1. To be able to run two jobs concurrently, you will need to purchase two parallel jobs if you are currently on the free tier. The first purchase only removes the time limits on the first job.

**Self-hosted agent**

To use self-hosted parallel jobs, you need to deploy [self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops) on your machines. You can register any number of these self-hosted agents in your organization. Microsoft charges based on the number of jobs you want to run at a time, not the number of agents registered.

- Public project: Unlimited parallel jobs.
- Private project: One self-hosted parallel job. Additionally, for each
  active Visual Studio Enterprise subscriber who is a member of your
  organization, you get one additional self-hosted parallel job.

For private project,when the free tier is no longer sufficient, you can pay for additional capacity per parallel job. [Buy self-hosted parallel jobs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.build-release-private-pipelines).There are no time limits on self-hosted jobs.

These are stated in the document, you can refer to the link in Daniel's comment for details.

Comment: My Question is not about parallel jobs, but it is about parallel releases from the same defnition

Comment: The essence of running multiple releases is actually running multiple jobs, and jobs are at the organizational level. It can be intuitively seen from the [agent pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5pyq.png) that the jobs are actually run on the agent.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I am currently deploying an my agent pool shows no jobs and my parallel jobs show not activity. But my deployments seem to be limited to 3 at a time for some reason.